# sitecore solr Problem accessing /solr//admin/cores

Tags: solr

I'm seeing failure to connect logs for all solr cores they all have problem accessing `/solr//admin/cores`. reason not found.

Here's the thing the `/solr//admin/cores` page doesn't exists while the `/solr/admin/cores` page does. I'm trying to establish why it is attempting to connect to this double forward slash url, as well as looking to see where can I change this url.

Comment: What is your `ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress` setting set to? Should be `https://YOURSOLRHOST:8983/solr` (notice the lack of a trailing `/`)

Comment: What is the specific error message you're receiving? Can you post the info from the logs? Also, what is the value of your `ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress` setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you jrap you were right in the defaultIndexConfiguration.config the `ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress` was https://localhost:8983/solr/# updated it to https://localhost:8983/solr and all is well in sitecore land